# Trouble with Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

The string is:  `1/9/2017`

My regex is: `/([0-9]{1,2})\/[0-9]{1,2}\/([0-9]{4})/`

Here's my line of code:

```
  def session_formatter(string)
    if string =~ /([0-9]{1,2})\/[0-9]{1,2}\/([0-9]{4})/
      year = $2
      if $1 =~ /8|9|10|11/
        "Fall " + year
      elsif $1 =~ /1|2|3/
        "Spring " + year
      else
        string
      end
    end
  end
```

I have `1/9/2017` returned instead of `Spring 2017` and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: For sure have a look here, a awesome tool to quick check your regex: http://rubular.com

Comment: Let me know if anyone needs any more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than deal with a regex I'd use:

```
str = '1/9/2017'

mm, dd, yyyy = str.split('/')
case mm.to_i
when 1, 2, 3
  "Spring #{yyyy}"
when 8, 9, 10
  "Fall #{yyyy}"
else
  str
end
# => "Spring 2017"
```

Regex are great but people love to use them so much they overlook ways the task could be done more simply. Not everything is a nail waiting to be hit with the regex hammer.

Splitting on `/` reduces the visual noise and using `to_i` makes it much easier to read and understand what the `when` are doing.

Alternately, use the Date class, which has all sorts of goodness:

```
require 'date'

str = '1/9/2017'

date = Date.strptime(str, '%m/%d/%Y')
case date.month
when 1, 2, 3
  "Spring #{date.year}"
when 8, 9, 10
  "Fall #{date.year}"
else
  str
end
# => "Spring 2017"
```

I used `strptime` because date formats aren't consistent around the world. Ruby, being an international language, uses the most common format dd/mm/yyyy for `Date.parse(...)`, which can run into problems when parsing U.S.-based dates. Instead `strptime` lets me force the parser into using a U.S.-based mm/dd/yyyy form:

```
require 'date'

Date.strptime('31/12/2001', '%d/%m/%Y') # => #<Date: 2001-12-31 ((2452275j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.strptime('31/12/2001', '%m/%d/%Y') # => ArgumentError: invalid date

# ~> ArgumentError
# ~> invalid date
```

Note that the first example falls prey to this particular problem. When dealing with dates it's really important that you know where the user is coming from if you allow them to enter a date as a free-formatted string, so you can at least guess what order the values are in. A better, more user-friendly, solution is to use a form that has a date-picker of some sort, that forces the order into what your code expects. Dealing with dates incorrectly can cause major havoc with calculations involving time or money, and you just don't want to have that happen.

If the date is part of text in a file then it's a bit easier to deal with, because it should be consistently formatted, but the order is still important to know.

If you *really* insist on using a pattern, I'd go about it like this:

```
str = '1/9/2017'
/(?<mm>[0-9]{1,2})\/[0-9]{1,2}\/(?<yyyy>[0-9]{4})/ =~ str 

mm # => "1"
yyyy # => "2017"

case mm.to_i
when 1, 2, 3
  "Spring #{yyyy}"
when 8, 9, 10
  "Fall #{yyyy}"
else
  str
end
# => "Spring 2017"
```

Or, for added fun:

```
str = '1/9/2017'
matches = /(?<mm>[0-9]{1,2})\/[0-9]{1,2}\/(?<yyyy>[0-9]{4})/.match(str)

mm, yyyy = matches[:mm], matches[:yyyy]

case mm.to_i
when 1, 2, 3
  "Spring #{yyyy}"
when 8, 9, 10
  "Fall #{yyyy}"
else
  str
end
# => "Spring 2017"
```

See Ruby's [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing) documentation for "named capture groups".

Comment: Extra "added fun" use the block form of `String#match` :)

Answer (score 1):

You are re-writing the `$1` variable with the subsequent regex checks. Assign it to a separate variable and use for further checking.

```
def session_formatter(string)
    if string =~ /([0-9]{1,2})\/[0-9]{1,2}\/([0-9]{4})/
      year = $2
      month = $1
      if month =~ /8|9|10|11/
        "Fall " + year
      elsif month =~ /1|2|3/
        "Spring " + year
      else
        string
      end
    end
  end
```

See the [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/gdrSCO)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using named grouping in regex and a simple Hash lookup:

```
TIME_OF_YEAR = { 'Winter' => [12,1,2], 
                 'Spring' => [3,4,5],
                 'Summer' =>  [6,7,8], 
                 'Fall' => [9,10,11]}

def session_formatter(string)
   string.match(/(?<month>[0-9]{1,2})\/[0-9]{1,2}\/(?<year>[0-9]{4})/) do |m|
     TIME_OF_YEAR.detect {|_,v| v.include? (m[:month].to_i)}.first + " #{m[:year]}"
   end
end

dates = ["1/9/2017", "2/9/2017", "3/9/2017", "4/9/2017", "5/9/2017", "6/9/2017", "7/9/2017", "8/9/2017",
"9/9/2017", "10/9/2017", "11/9/2017", "12/9/2017"]

puts dates.map {|d| session_formatter(d)}
```

This uses named grouping in regex and the block form of match to allow you to look up the time of year in the `TIME_OF_YEAR` hash in a nice succinct way.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/cNzs8l)